# XML parsing of some special characters using SAX parser in Android

Tags: android, character-encoding, xml-parsing, special-characters, saxparser

I made a xml parser using [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/) example (Listing 6. The SAX handler). I have to parse the file which is coming from the server. The file received from server has "ISO-8859-1" encoding.

The problem is that received file from server has some special characters like &, ", ' etc. I know server should send `&amp;` instead of `&`, but server will send & only, it cannot replace & to `&amp;` due to some other problems. I also do inputSource.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1"). I want to parse this file, but parser cannot parse these special characters. What should i do? Any help....

I have another doubt is that "The charset of ISO-8859-1 has these special characters then why parser cannot parse these special characters?"

Comment: I have error like :      org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: not well-formed (invalid token)

Comment: What is the first line of your XML file? "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>" ?

Comment: Just a try: set your InputSource manually to ISO like inputSource.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1") and then pass it to SAX parser's parse()

Comment: I have already set encoding to ISO-8859-1 and i have written this in my question also.

Comment: Oh, right. Another try: test your XML against another validator like this one http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp. If no errors occur provide your code (initialization of the SAX parser...not the handler) and the first lines of your XML so someone can reproduce the error

Answer (score 0):

You can [parse as XPL](http://hll.nu/xpl/xpl1.htm) and then run the results through any XML process. XPL is just like XML except that it allows special characters in text elements (this is the reason it exists). The XPL process also generates XML output in the specified encoding (or defaults to UTF-8 if not specified).